# Retain changes to existing files when publishing

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I'm stuck in a scenario where my published file is initially correct, but then later is replaced by it's original version. I suspect that the order of events is wrong, coupled with what's in the root directory.

Essentially I have successfully setup my publishing environment where it executes a custom command to create some JavaScript (which gets created outside of my project). Because a file in source control needs to reference this newly created JavaScript, I am simply copying the file (MyControl.ascx) to a temp location (thus it loses the read lock by TFS) and I am having the custom command update the references to the JS. Once this is done, I gather all the files (custom JavaScript, as well as edited MyControl.ascx in it's temp location) and publish.

It publishes everything first, so I see the new JS as well as the updated MyControl.ascx, but a few minutes later it finishes the publish, and Control looks like how it looked in the root directory.

I think what's happening is it's just pushing out what's in the root (which includes MyControl.ascx) on top of my custom Control (which is in another directory).

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn>
       CustomCollectFiles;
       $(PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn);
     </PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
     Exec Command="MyCommand.bat"
     <ItemGroup>
         <_BundledJS Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\Includes\javascript\*.js" />
         <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_BundledJS.Identity)">
            <DestinationRelativePath>Includes\javascript\%(Filename)%(Extension)   
            </DestinationRelativePath>
         </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
     </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
     <_UpdatedControl Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\TempArea\MyControl.ascx" />
     <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_UpdatedControl.Identity)">
          <DestinationRelativePath>Controls\%(Filename)%(Extension)
          </DestinationRelativePath>
     </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

So you can see above i'm taking something that's in ....\TempArea\MyControl.ascx and pushing it out to Controls\%(Filename)%(Extension).

Any ideas how I can tell it to essentially retain my ....\TempArea\MyControl.ascx without then overwriting it with the original MyControl.ascx within the project (....\Controls\MyControl.ascx) ?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

So I actually ended up figuring it out, and wanted to share:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <_UpdatedControl Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\TempArea\MyControl.ascx" />
     <FilesForPackagingFromProject Remove="Controls\MyControl.ascx" ></FilesForPackagingFromProject>
     <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_UpdatedControl.Identity)" >
       <DestinationRelativePath>Controls\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)    </DestinationRelativePath>
     </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
   </ItemGroup>
```

So you can see here it actually removes the original control, then adds it back.

I also changed the target as such:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OnAfterPipelineCollectFilesPhase>
    CustomCollectFiles;
    $(OnAfterPipelineCollectFilesPhase);
  </OnAfterPipelineCollectFilesPhase>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Let me know if any questions would be happy to help!